# Cannot find some "Type" methods / extensions in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

What package defines the following methods for **Type**? :

- IsGenericType
- GetGenericArguments
- Assembly
- BaseType

**/// Update ///**
After reading the answer from @Victor Hurdugaci :
All the extensions/methods should be accessed via `.GetTypeInfo().`, correct?

Comment: I've created a small helper project https://github.com/StefH/ReflectionBridge which adds some extension methods for bridging between extensions on Type to TypeInfo. A NuGet is also available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the unofficial package search to identify the package in which a type is located http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/

- `IsGenericType` in `System.Reflection` (for CoreCLR/aspnetcore50 only)
- `GetGenericArguments` in `System.Reflection` (for CoreCLR/aspnetcore50 only)
- `Assembly` in `System.Runtime` (for CoreCLR/aspnetcore50 only)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I already used this one. Can you please check my updated text in the question?